# How to pass parmeters to functions inside tf.cond in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, if-statement, tensorflow

I have following simple placeholders:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1])
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1])
```

There are two functions `fn1` and `fn2` defined as:

```
def fn1(a, b): 
    return tf.mul(a, b)
def fn2(a, b): 
    return tf.add(a, b)
```

Now I want to calculate result based on pred condition:

```
pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=[1])
result = tf.cond(pred, fn1(x,y), fn2(y,z))
```

But it gives me an error saying `fn1 and fn2 must be callable`.

How can I write `fn1` and `fn2` so that they can receive parameters at runtime?
I want to call the following:

```
sess.run(result, feed_dict={x:1,y:2,z:3,pred:True})
```

Answer (score 23):

You can pass parameters to the functions using **lambda** and the code is as bellows.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def fn1(a, b):
  return tf.mul(a, b)

def fn2(a, b):
  return tf.add(a, b)

pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
result = tf.cond(pred, lambda: fn1(x, y), lambda: fn2(y, z))
```

Then you can call it as bellowing:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, pred: True})
  # The result is 2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest would be to define your functions in the call:

```
result = tf.cond(pred, lambda: tf.mul(a, b), lambda: tf.add(a, b))
```